# PThreads: Read/Write Lock: How to check if thread holds the write lock?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, posix, readerwriterlock

I am implementing a wrapper around pthread_rwlock_t for iphone dev.
Docs say that acquiring a read lock after acquiring a write lock is undefined.
Does POSIX allow me to query whether I already have the write lock?
Or, what is the best way of preventing this situation from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your wrapper should keep track of whether it already has the write lock held in that thread. You can do this in a number of ways, but looking at how popular libraries ilke [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html) or [ACE](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html) do it would probably help.

You should consider using one of those existing libraries and skip the worries and effort of re-implementing what has probably been done before.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. ACE is a little heavy for iphone dev. boost would be appropriate, because it is mostly header files.